# How to keep alive socket.io connection when app is in Background in iOS?

Tags: ios, socket.io

How to keep alive socket.io connection when app is in Background in iOS

Comment: iOS doesn't allow background execution of WebSockets as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think iOS allows you to connect Socket.io in background mode. You can establish a connection once your app comes into foreground or app becomes active.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot keep your socket connection alive in the background. However, by using this code in your AppDelegate's applicationDidEnterBackground you can keep your socket connection alive for 30 seconds:

```
let app = UIApplication.shared

var bgTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier?
        
bgTask = app.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: {
    app.endBackgroundTask(bgTask!)
})
```

I would suggest that you should handle background and foreground scenarios manually to minimize connection redundancies.